Using Python Reflex data_table component, how can I change the color of the table headings to blue? using rx.heading does not work
given the provided python reflex code, how can I change the color of the table headings to blue? using rx.heading does not work.  I also tried: heading_style={"color": "blue"} with no result.
'''
class State(rx.State):
    data: List = [
        ["Lionel", "Messi", "PSG"],
        ["Christiano", "Ronaldo", "Al-Nasir"],
    ]
    columns: List[str] = ["First Name", "Last Name"]

def index():
    return rx.data_table(
        data=State.data,
        columns=State.columns,
        style={
            "rx.heading": {
                "color": "blue",  # Set the color to blue
            }
        }
    )
'''

